# How to set a loading boolean on component during Redux api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm creating a project based on [React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react), [Redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux) and [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).

On the following example I list every "project" and allow user to "Increment" (who make a 1sec fake call to API) and update a state on MainApp Component (to display loading)

**Question:** 
How to I catch when the `incrementProject` action is completed directly into the MainApp Component ?

I search a lot's about it but didn't found anything.. What's the best to handle cases like that?

**Ideas:**

- Create all states into the Redux Project Store and handle all loading states globally ? (I fear about how the code will be heavier :/)
- Send a callback into `incrementProject(projectId, next)` and call it from the action after dispatching the error or success ?

---

I didn't include all actions/reducers/api call because it's very basic code.

**MainApp Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { requestProjects, incrementProject } from '../actions';

class MainApp extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loadingProjectsIds: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { requestProjects } = this.props;
    requestProjects();
  }

  render() {

    const { projectStore, incrementProject } = this.props;
    const { loadingProjectsIds } = this.state;

    const incrementProject = (project) => {
      let ids = this.state.loadingProjectsIds;
      ids.push(project._id);
      this.setState({
        loadingProjectsIds: ids
      });

      incrementProject(project._id);
    }

    return (
      <ul>
          {projectStore.projects.map(project => (
            <li key={`project-${project.key}`}>
              {project.name} 
              {
                loadingProjectsIds.indexOf(project._id) !== -1) 
                ? Incrementing...
                : <a>Increment</a>
              }
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
};

export default connect((state) => { project } = state), (dispatch) => ({
  requestProjects: () => dispatch(requestProjects()),
  incrementProject: (_id) => dispatch(incrementProject(_id)),
})(MainApp);
```

**Increment Action**

```
export function incrementProject(projectId) {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: 'PROJECT_INC', projectId});

    let { err, payload } = await API.incProject({projectId});

    if (err) {
      dispatch({type: 'PROJECT_INC_ERR', err});
    }
    else {
      dispatch({type: 'PROJECT_INC_SUCCESS', payload});
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a best solution. Everything depends on who is interested if a given `action` is being dispatched. A more generic approach (which we use) is to have a `TOGGLE_LOADING` action and a `loading` property in your reducer. Something like this

```
const initialState = {
    value : '',
    loading: false,
    error: false
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'TOGGLE_LOADING' : return{
            ...state,
            loading : !state.loading
        }

        case 'STORE_VALUE' : return{
            ...state,
            loading: false
        }

        case 'ERROR_FETCHING' : return{
            ...state,
            loading : false,
            error: true,
        }

        default : return state
    }
}
```

And inside your `action creator`

```
const fetchValue = () =>{
    return dispatch =>{
        dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_LOAD'})
        apiCall()
            .then(value =>{
                dispatch({type: 'STORE_VALUE'})
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                dispatch({type: 'FETCH_ERROR'})
            })
    }
}
```

Now you have a `loading` property configured in your `state`. Just use it inside your components

```
   class Component extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        fetchValue()
    }

    render(){
        const { loading } = this.props
        return loading ? 'Loading' : <Content />
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay but in my case I have to handle a state for every project. So I have to create an array of element on my store and update only one by one. You think that handle everything globally (into reducer) isn't a problem ?

Comment: As long as you don't have two components depending on the same property at the same time this solution will work everywhere. Here we have a single `loading` prop used across multiple components. But if our use case needs more granularity you should use multiple properties.

Comment: Why did 2 components can't have dependencies into the same property ?

Comment: Let's say you have `ComponentA` dispatching `TOGGLE_LOAD` and waiting for the an API call. At the same time you have `ComponentB` also dispatching `TOGGLE_LOAD` which will lead to `ComponentA` reading the incorrect value from `loading`

Comment: Ho okok, I understand it based on your code with a toogle function, Thx